# Jquery bind()/live() within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a little pager which removes and rewrites content. I have a function called after loading the page, it shall be executed after changing the page as well. Because I do not wat to implement the function twice (on initialisation and after changing the page) I tried bind()/live() and a simple function.

The function looks like this:

```
jQuery('.blogentry').each(function (){
    jQuery(this).click(function(){
        //Clicking on the element opens a layer, definitely works - I tested it
    });
});
```

It is executed after initialisation, for executing it after page changes as well I tried the following:

```
jQuery('.nextPage, .prevPage').click(function changePage(){
    // Changing page and rewriting content
    showEntry();
});
//...
showEntry();
//...
function showEntry(){
jQuery('.blogentry').each(function (){
    jQuery(this).click(function(){
        //Clicking on the element opens a layer, definitely works - I tested it
    });
});
}
```

But the function is not executed if put inside a function (*lol*) and called via showEntry();

Afterwards I tried to bind the function...

```
jQuery('.nextPage, .prevPage').click(function changePage(){
    // Changing page and rewriting content
    jQuery('.blogentry').bind("click", showEntry);
});
//...
jQuery(this).click(function showEntry(){
    //Clicking on the element opens a layer, definitely works - I tested it
});
```

Did not work either. Code after the bind()-line would not execute as well.
I thought maybe it's a problem to bind to an event function, if an event is already given via the parameter so i also tried this:

```
jQuery('.nextPage, .prevPage').click(function changePage(){
    // Changing page and rewriting content
    jQuery('.blogentry').bind("click", showEntry);
});
//...
function showEntry(){
    //Clicking on the element opens a layer, definitely works - I tested it
});
}
```

No success at all. Maybe I cannot call the function from inside the function regarding to the bind()? Maybe I just do not understand the bind()-function at all? I also tried the live() function since it seemed to fit better, as I am rewriting the content all the time. But it had the same effect: none...

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to bind a function to a click event, within another click event?

Comment: What is the code doing that changes the page? Is it doing an Ajax call? In that case what might be happening is that the bind method inside the paging function might be executing before the page has loaded via ajax and therefore has no effect. If that is the case, try calling bind in a success handler for the relevant Ajax call.

Comment: Yeah, but the first click event changes and rewrites the content, so afterwards the new written elements shall be bound again to the function which opens a layer. That function is a click event as well and is initalised at the beginning, but shall be executed when the content is rewritten

Comment: i think what he means is on click of sm control the page layout changes after which he needs to bind a click event on sm new controls on the page.. an ideal contender for live though.. but nt sure what your problem is

Comment: can you host your code on jsfiddle or something

Comment: see below - your code simply needs the click event to work for new instances of .blogentry being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this should be

```
jQuery('.blogentry').live('click', function() { /* onclick handler */ });
```

This should bind the function to every blogentry on the page at the moment of the call and all the blogentries that are added to the page later on.

Additional notes:

In `$(foo).each(function() { $(this).click(fun); });` the each is unnecessary - `$(foo).click(fun);` is enough.

`$(foo).bind('click', fun);` is functionally equivalent to `$(foo).click(fun)` - it does not matter which one you use.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much. I just thoght too complicated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate or bind. don't call the function like that, just create a delegate with .blogentry and it should update even after you load a new page via ajax. It will automatically do this.

`$("#blogcontainer").delegate(".blogentry", "click", function(){ //open layer });`

Comment: Thank you! The live()-solution worked for me, but I am sure with delegate it would have worked fine as well!

Comment: @samiSalami just a note that delegate should be used over live(). the performance is a lot better.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep it in mind and change that probably, though I don't have any performance problems so far (there is not that much going on on the page ;-) ).

Comment: @SamiSalami you might not have problems with performance, but other people could. Different browsers, slower computers etc... It may not make much of a difference, but you just never know. even if you do `$(document).delegate(....)`, it's still faster than live. Try it out, it's a simple change and if it works keep it, if not go back to live.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
$(body).delegate(".blogentry", "click", function(){
    showEntry();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose the live()-solution but I am sure it would have worked with delegate() as well!

Comment: both are fine. delegate is simply faster as live requires document as the parent element and delegate allow you to specify the closest parent. i.e. where body is could change to $('#container') being the wrapper around the clickable element

Answer (score 1):

alternaltivly you can use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#blogcontainer').click( function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).is('.blogentry') ) {
      // do your stuff
    }
  });
});
```

hence, no need to bind each blogentry at creation or reload, and it's (slightly) faster.